# Convert a list formatted as string in a list

Tags: r, string, evaluation

i have this list in R:

```
x[[82]]["PositionNormalized"]
$PositionNormalized
$PositionNormalized$X
[1] -0.678095

$PositionNormalized$Y
[1] -0.970294
```

I've converted it in a string like so:

```
list=as.character(x[[82]]["PositionNormalized"])
list
[1] "list(X = -0.678095, Y = -0.970294)"
```

How can I reconvert the last string back into a list object?

Comment: try: `eval(parse(text = list))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by @missuse, you could use `eval` and `parse`. The latter will create an expression, which is then evaluated to return a list object.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
lst <- list(list(list(x = 123, y = "test")))
lst
eval(parse(text = as.character(lst[[1]])))
```

You could also use this to run code as shown in [this example](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-August/285614.html).